# How to target a single view in a ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to the iOS developer world and I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to target a single View created in a ForEach loop.

Basically I have three shapes (flags), and I would like to add the functionality of having a flag rotate 360 degrees when the flag is tapped. I have the animation (rotation) part working but my problem is that I'm not able to figure out how to target the single flag that was tapped, instead the animations is executed by all three flags.

```
ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { number in

                    Button(action: {
                        self.flagTapped(number)

                        withAnimation {
                            self.animationAmount += 360
                        }

                        self.askQuestion()

                    }) {
                        FlagImage(name: self.countries[number], number: number)
                    }
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.animationAmount), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
                }
```

This is my code so far, what it does is what I explained before, it does the 360 rotation but for all three flags instead of the one that is being tapped, I also tried doing something with onTapGesture but that didn't seem to work. I would appreciate some help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo how this could be done (I used some standard things in your snapshot due to absent custom values, but the idea should be obvious).

[image: SwiftUI rotate clicked button]

```
struct TestTargetButton: View {
    let countries = ["shield", "triangle", "square"]

    @State var selection: Int? = nil
    @State var animationAmount: Double = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { number in

                Button(action: {
                    self.selection = number
                    withAnimation {
                        self.animationAmount += 360
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: self.countries[number])
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .padding()
                }
                .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.selection == number ? self.animationAmount : 0), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be working! Would you mind explaining how does it work? @Asperi

Comment: Button action change selection number to own in `self.selection = number`, and rotation is applied only to selected number in `rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.selection == number ? self.animationAmount : 0)`

Comment: How does the rotation3DEffect only gets applied to the selected number in the .degree() modifier when that modifier is only supposed to accept a Double. and I know we give it one but how does ```self.selection == number ? self.animationAmount : 0  ``` makes SwiftUI to select a specific view? @Asperi

Comment: It does not select anything, on @State change the view stack is rebuild and effect is applied to button with selected number and `0` for others.